# How can i access control name of MapControl inside a Hub Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I want create a mapcontrol inside the Hub control, but everytime i tryed access from CS file,i can't find the name! Here is the code!

```
<HubSection Header="Rotas e Mapas" Foreground="White">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Maps:MapControl
        x:Name="MapControl1"
        MapServiceToken="ubgfhnhduyekheddjd"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your map control is inside a `DataTemplate`. It exists in the Visual Tree and not the Logical tree. I'd recommend you to read this article on the subject - [How to access a named control inside a XAML DataTemplate (using CSharp)](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i will tryed to use in my mapcontrol

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the Loaded event of the MapControl control, and inside it cast the sender parameter to MapControl and assign it to a page variable.

```
  <HubSection Header="Map">
    <HubSection.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Maps:MapControl Loaded="MapControl_Loaded" ...


  public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
  {
    private MapControl map;
    ...

    private async void MapControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      map = (MapControl)sender;

      map.Style = MapStyle.Aerial;        
      ...
```

Comment: I get it, but how can i use the control name of my map?which was "MapControl1"

Comment: well, you can't directly because it is in a DataTemplate ... to learn more, you can follow the link in the answer posted by Darius V. You can still name your page variable "MapControl1", but you still have to manually assign it in code

Comment: ok,i will read, it's seems easy in exemple of ListBox, i will try to do in map, thanks for your help!